# Proper way to redirect user to another activity after when using startActivityForSignInWithProvider?

Tags: java, firebase, microsoft-oauth

I am new to using firebase auth with providers so bear with me.

In the documentation for FirebaseAuth using microsoft, it says:

*
Authenticate with Firebase using the OAuth provider object. Note that unlike other FirebaseAuth operations, this will take control of your UI by popping up a Custom Chrome Tab. As a result, do not reference your Activity in the OnSuccessListener and OnFailureListener that you attach as they will immediately detach when the operation starts the UI.*

I am not quite sure what it means by "do not reference your Activity". Does it mean I cannot start an activity in the onSuccess listener? if so what is the proper way for me to redirect the users to another activity?

```
firebaseAuth
        .startActivityForSignInWithProvider(/* activity= */ this, provider.build())
        .addOnSuccessListener(
                new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                        // User is signed in.
                        // DO I NOT REDIRECT THE USER HERE?
                        Intent intent= new Intent(AuthActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        //Is the above a code a No-No?

                    }
                })
        .addOnFailureListener(
                new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // Handle failure.
                    }
                });
```